# Is the multiplicity of the zero of a holomorphic function is constant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}^{n},n\geq 2$ and $f:\Omega\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. Define $ord_{a}f$ to be the total order of f at the point $a$ (also called the multiplicity of the zero of the function $f$ at the point $a$). If the zero set of $f$, namely $Z(f)$ is assumed to be non-empty, connected and irreducible, then is it true that $ord_{z}f$ is constant $\forall z\in Z(f)~?$

Comment: I'm not familiar with these definitions, but what about $n=2$ and $f(z,w) = zw$? Compare the order of $f$ at the origin versus elsewhere on the coordinate axes.

Comment: @Hurkyl : I would try something like this : a zero of an analytic function $f: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ is a closed analytic subset of complex dimension $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ where the order of vanishing (ie. with respect to a non-tangent curve) is constant almost everywhere ? Then the formal sum of all those sets is the divisor of $f$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: $Z(f)$ is also assumed to be irreducible. Thanks for raising that point.

Comment: @Sam: You can have the same feature when the zero set is irreducible; e.g. $f(z,w) = z^2 - w^3 - w^2$.

Comment: In general the set $A_k \{ z \in \Omega : \text{ord}_z(f) \geq k\}$ will be closed in $\Omega$ and will verify $ A_{k+1} \subset \overline{(A_k \backslash A_{k+1})}$ and $A_1$ will be an hypersurface but this is more or less all what you can say I think ...

Comment: @Hurkyl What is the divisor of $f(z,w) = z^2 - w^3 - w^2$ ? Is it an analytic curve $\gamma$ (*) self-intersecting at $(0,0)$ ? (ie. $\gamma=  \bigcup_j \gamma_j(U_j)$ where each $U_j$ is a simply connected open $\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma_j$ is analytic $U_j \to \mathbb{C}^2$)